# Could a translation error lead to squares to not be considered as rectangles?

Tags: traducción, definiciones, españa, matemáticas

I'm reading a certain set of kindergarten/lower primary maths textbooks that is written by North American authors for a European company.

Whenever students are asked to identify the number of rectangles in a given picture, the answer booklet gives the number of oblongs instead of the number of rectangles.

While the topic may be too advanced for kindergarten students, the maths textbooks indeed explicitly say at the bottom of the first page of a textbook at the very first level to tell students that squares are special types of rectangles, where levels 1-4 are for kindergarten students.

Additionally, the accompany guide for teachers devotes a whole page of discussion as to how to teach that squares are special types of rectangles. There's even a paragraph about teaching to kindergarten students. The authors/some of the co-authors of the teacher guides are also authors/co-authors of the textbooks. They have also said that if students are taught that squares are not rectangles, then they will have misconceptions later.

Perhaps, the ones who wrote the answer booklets were not fluent in English while the ones who wrote the textbooks were.

For example

> [picture with 4 circles, 2 triangles, 3 square rectangles, 2 oblong rectangles for a total of 5 rectangles]
>
> Circle ___
>
> Triangle ___
>
> Square ___
>
> Rectangle ___

The answer key would give only the numbers:

> 4
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 2

So, the last line is wrong since it should be 5.

Could this happen in Spanish? Or a Spanish dialect? I mean, is there something specific about the translations of any of the following words 'rectangle, square, oblong, quadrilateral, quadrangle, parallelogram, trapezoid/trapezium, rhombus' that would cause such confusion? I guess the translator/s thought that when English speakers say 'rectangle', it means 'oblong in their language/dialect, but I don't see that as specifically a problem for this particular language.

P.S. I'm a monolinguist.

Related:

[In what curricula are “rectangles” defined so as to exclude squares?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13700/in-what-curricula-are-rectangles-defined-so-as-to-exclude-squares)

Comment: Hello BCLC and welcome to [spanish.se]! Since translations may be picky, some pictures would really help grasp the full idea of what you are referring to. For example, Wordreference says that [oblong](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=oblong) is a synonym of rectangle in Spanish.

Comment: Also, technically speaking a square is a type of rectangle, only that with all sides being the same long. So rectangles = squares + oblongs. However, in common speaking people would not agree on that and would think that rectangles and squares are different things.

Comment: When a primary math textbook is written, often the exercises are farmed out to cheaper labor than the authors whose names appear on the title page.  In this day and age, the exercises more and more don't get checked by somebody who knows what they're doing. // I've found through experience that it is possible for five-year-olds to give an answer that a mathematician would consider correct. // Also note that primary school teachers are, most of them, math phobic to a high degree.

Comment: @aparente001 You mean the writing of some of the exercises or some of the answer keys were probably delegated and not necessarily written by the main authors? Thanks!

Comment: @walen Thanks for the reminder. My question has not yet been answered.

Comment: @bclc - What I have seen is that some teaching materials contain some badly posed questions.  If there's an answer posted for a badly posed question, it will necessarily be nonsense.  The underlying problem is the badly posed exercise, in general.  I will say that when I was supplementing my children's math learning, in kindergarten and early elementary, I used a combination of Singapore Math books and homemade materials.  Do check out math educators, it's a great SE site. // In short, the mess you found is extremely unlikely to have anything to do with translation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about mathematics and only tangentially, if at all, about the Spanish language.

Comment: @aparente001 math educators was the first SE site I went to. Thanks anyhoo

Comment: @mdewey how is my question on-topic on Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese, Italian, russian, french SE?

Comment: I reread your question.  I apologize for not reading it carefully enough before.  I think they hired someone at a lower pay scale to write the answer booklet.  I've had some similar experiences.

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks :') [No need to be sorry.](https://www.boredpanda.com/stop-saying-sorry-say-thank-you-comic-yao-xiao/)

Comment: Please, try to firstly clarify the scope of the question and, then, only then, start bounties. Please go through the comments carefully to be sure you make the question fit in the site. It may be useful to read [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). I am removing the bounty in the meanwhile just to prevent the bounty be used to circumvent the closing votes. Thanks for the understanding!

Comment: @fedorqui Ok you caught me. I didn't read well into comments and just wanted to set bounties. [Thanks for the BOTD. Sorry](http://www.boredpanda.com/stop-saying-sorry-say-thank-you-comic-yao-xiao/) for being a dishonest asshole and [hypocrite](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/revisions/13700/4).

Comment: @BCLC remember the [Be nice](/help/be-nice) policy. As per your question, it seems to all of us that the question was already answered long ago and it is unclear what is that you are still wondering. Feel free to [edit] it to clarify the scope, taking into consideration [what topics you can and what you cannot ask in here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: @mdewey how come i can ask this in german se, russian se, portugese se, italian se, japanese se, korean se, chinese se, etc but not spanish se?

Answer (score 4):

The translation of the solution is right.
I wouldn't say that the translation of the *exercise* is grammatically wrong, but it doesn't agree with that of the solution (which is right) so... it'd probably be better to rewrite the exercise.

What you call "oblong rectangle" is what in Spanish is considered a ***[rectángulo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VWKcB1u)***: a parallelogram with four right angles in which contiguous sides are **not** of the same length.
*Rectángulo* can also be used as an adjective to mean any figure with right angles (so "right triangle" would be *triángulo rectángulo*, etc.) but, as a noun, it is specifically a rectangle (an oblong one, I mean).

What you call "square rectangle" is what in Spanish is considered a ***[cuadrado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BPG9fIn)***: a figure with four equal-length sides and four right angles.

So yes: **the picture contains *4 círculos, 2 triángulos, 3 cuadrados y 2 rectángulos***.

Re: squares being just a type of rectangle: geometrically speaking, probably yes, and mathematicians might use the word *rectángulo* in a square-inclusive sense, but the relevance of such a concept outside of the field of Pure Maths and the usefulness of teaching it to little kids are off-topic here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74991/discussion-on-answer-by-walen-could-a-translation-error-lead-to-squares-to-not-b).

Comment: I teach mathematics at secondary school in Spain (I teach in Catalan, but I also use Spanish at lessons because we are really a bilingual community) and I would say that the RAE definition of rectangle is wrong. It makes no sense to say that this is the definition of rectangle except for mathematicians. Let's imagine the situation of a student who has doubts, so he or she consults the dictionary...

Comment: “A student with doubts about the mathematical concept of rectangle should check a Maths book, not a dictionary”: while correct in principle, what use would dictionaries be, if we candidly admit that they may contain wrong definitions?

Comment: And, in this way, RAE can contribute to the lack of scientific culture of our country... Nice.

Comment: Just for the record, I think the solution is wrong, and I don't think the error occurred due to translation factors.

Comment: [Mapa de diccionarios](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub) shows that the entry _m. Geom. Paralelogramo que tiene los cuatro ángulos rectos y los lados contiguos desiguales_ was added to the dictionary by 1884.

Comment: It seems that RAE has added a [new entry](https://dle.rae.es/rect%C3%A1ngulo), so that now definitions 2 and 3 of "rectángulo" contradict each other.